# Calculate perceived angle of a ray at a known distance from origin of actual ray without distance metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, trigonometry

So lets say I have a camera at origin, and the camera perceives the direction vector of angle(θ) of an object in its field of view. I have another device(lidar) at a known distance of "r" behind the camera. I need to calculate the direction/angle(Φ) perceived by the new device(lidar) without knowing how far away the object that was initially detected is actually sitting at

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lKsk.png)

"h" = Arbitrary distance of object from center line (Not Known)

"x" = Vertical distance of object from center line (Not Known)

"r" = Offset distance of new device origin point (Known)

"θ" = Direction angle of object perceived at the original point (Known)

"Φ" = Direction angle to be calculated

Since we can use traditional trigonometry to find the relation between the variables mentioned above, I was able to come to this relationship

```
tan(Φ) = tan(θ) * (x / (x+r))
```

However here, while both θ and "r" are known values, "x" can vary from 0 to infinity. So is there a way to come up with a solution. The only hint I was given was "Taylor's series" but am not sure how to use that to approximate a good value for Φ. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Not enough data. With $x$ unknown, the object can be anywhere at the line 'angle theta' so 'phi' can be anything between zero and 'theta'.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

The camera data tells you that the object is somewhere on the green ray you have drawn at angle $\theta$ from the LIDAR/camera ray.  You have drawn the red ray from the LIDAR, but that ray is misleading : the information from the camera only restricts the object to be somewhere on the green ray, so there are a range of angles that $\phi$ may be hence there is no definite direction for the red ray from the LIDAR.

By itself, that means the angle the LIDAR will report is anywhere from $0$ (the object is touching the camera) to $\theta$ (the object is infinitely far away).  With neither the focal distance between the object and the camera nor the range from the LIDAR to the camera, the angle $\phi$ is not specified by the data given.